# Powershell Command Line Winrar not creating file in expected location

Tags: powershell, command-line, zip, winrar

I have a Powershell script which should be zipping a specified directory at the specified location, it appears as though WinRAR does run and perform some kind of operation, however I cannot seem to locate where the zip file ends up in the file system.

The idea is that I will zip up a directory and then delete the unzipped directory from the file system.

The $filePath variable is the location of the directory to be zipped (inclusive of base location), the $rarExePath is the path to the WinRAR.exe

```
# zips up any files in the directory
function ZipDirectory($filePath, $rarExePath)
{
    "Zipping directory $filePath"

    #$zipFilePath = (Split-Path $filePath -Parent)

    $archiveName = (Split-Path $filePath -Leaf) + ".rar"

    "Zipping directory $dirPath to file $archiveName $zipFilePath"

    Start-Process $rarExePath -ArgumentList "a -r $archiveName $filePath"

    #Remove-Item -Recurse $filePath

    "Completed..."
}
```

Is there anything that is obviously wrong with my commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out what directory you're in when the script is running, by adding:

```
resolve-path .
```

to your script.

There's a good chance WinRAR is simply putting the file into the current directory and you don't know what that is.

I'd be changing the `$archiveName` variable to add the *explicit* path where I wanted the file created:

```
PS C:\Users\pax> $x = 'c:\desired\' + (split-path "c:\a\b\xyzzy" -leaf)

PS C:\Users\pax> $x
C:\desired\xyzzy
```

Comment: yep you are correct, it is outputting the file into the directory that the Powershell script resides in